# Not able to load class from Lib

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp and I want to include a file from Lib/Facebook directory, I am using 
App::uses('Facebook', 'Lib/Facebook');
but this is not working, I checked the syntax is right, there may be some configuration error. I am getting the error

> Error: Class 'Facebook' not found.

This is working correctly on windows, but now I shifted to linux and I'm getting this error. Please help.

Comment: So your class file is `Lib/Facebook/Facebook.php` and contains the class `Facebook`?

Comment: yes my class is Facebook.php, This is working correctly on windows, but now i shifted to linux and getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

If it works as expected in windows and not on linux then the mostly likely cause is improper filename casing. Windows has case insensitive file system while linux doesn't. Make sure your filename is exactly `Facebook.php` and not something like `facebook.php`.

Comment: this was a valid point, my Class name is "Facebook" so i used App::uses('Facebook', 'Lib/Facebook'); but still not working. File name is not required for app::uses. thanks for reply.

Comment: Filename might not be specified in App::uses() but CakePHP has a file naming convention. All class filenames should be CamelCased same as the classname itself.